# ASP.NET Core : get stored procedure results to a view model

Tags: asp.net-core, stored-procedures, viewmodel

I have a view model called TdetailsVM as below:

```
public class TdetailsVM 
{
    public Tournaments tourney { get; set; }
    public List<Participants> currentlyjoined { get; set; }
}
```

Now in the controller I am passing an ID of the tournament to the task:

```
public async Task<IactionResult> Details(guid id)
{
    var ThisTourney = _context.Tournaments.FirstOrDefaultAsync(m => m.TID == id);
```

This will return the value for a specific tournament into `ThisTourney` where I pass it later to the view model

I need something similar like:

```
var ThisParticipants = (result "has many rows" from a stored procedure called SP_GetParticipants that needs a parameter =id)
```

Then I can pass the values to the view model as below

```
TdetailsVM tvm = new TdetailsVM()
                     {
                          tourney = ThisTourney,
                          currentlyjoined = ThisParticipants
                     }

// then I can return the view 
return view(tvm);
```

Passing the data for the first requirement is fine and it works but how can I pass the stored procedure ?

Many thanks in advance

Comment: Side note if you're using SQL Server: you should **not** use the `sp_` prefix for your stored procedures. Microsoft has [reserved that prefix for its own use (see *Naming Stored Procedures*)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190669%28v=sql.105%29.aspx), and you do run the risk of a name clash sometime in the future. [It's also bad for your stored procedure performance](http://www.sqlperformance.com/2012/10/t-sql-queries/sp_prefix). It's best to just simply avoid `sp_` and use something else as a prefix - or no prefix at all!

Comment: I didn't know that .. thank you very much for the info

Comment: May I ask why you are not using an one-to-many relation from Tourney -> Participants?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are using Entity Framework Core, then for calling your stored procedure you can use this line of code.

```
List<Participants> participants= _context.Participants.FromSql("SP_GetParticipants @ID",id).ToList();
```

> Note how I passed `@ID` value to the stored procedure in `FromSql`
> method and how mapped the result to `List<Participants>`. Please have a look at [raw sql](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/querying/raw-sql) for more information.

After this line of code you have you list of `Participants`, then you can fill your parent ViewModel.

```
var result = new TdetailsVM 
        {
            Tourney = thisTourney,
            Currentlyjoined  = Participants
        };
```

> Note that it is recommended to use `PascalCase` for naming your public
> properties in your class (ViewModel) and `camelCase` for your
> private ones. Please take a look at [General Naming Conventions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/design-guidelines/general-naming-conventions)
> for more information.

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer .. this works perfectly when Participants is a model representing a table in the DB that has been defined in ApplicationDbContext .. what if Participants is not a model defined in  ApplicationDbContext and it is just a class defined with several fields properties inside the view model ?

Comment: I mean lets say that my TdetailsVM is like this    public class TdetailsVM 
{
    public Tournaments tourney { get; set; }
    public List<Participants> currentlyjoined { get; set; }
}      public class Participants
        {

            public string FirstName { get; set; }
            [Column(TypeName = "nvarchar(450)")]
            public DateTime JoinedTournamentOn { get; set; }
            public int GamesWon { get; set; }
            public int GamesLost { get; set; }
        }
 Is it possible to use stored procedures with classes not defined in applicationDbContext ?

Comment: Also, is there any tutorial somewhere on how to use stackoverflow to type a well formatted text ? my text comes up differently when I post

Comment: Yes, it is possible to map a normal class (not `DbContext` class). It just need to include the properties in the result of Stored Procedure. And finally a good resource to help you ask question is [Jon Skeet Guide](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question/)